# Use PyObject_Realloc correctly

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-extensions

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/objimpl.h#L83 says

> PyObject_Realloc(p != NULL, 0) does not return  NULL, or free the memory at p.

PyObject_Realloc doesn't free the memory.

I've noticed a memory leak in my program which uses PyObject_Realloc every now and then.

I tried to fix it using this:

```py
PyLongObject *new = (PyLongObject *) PyObject_Realloc(obj, new_size);
if (new == NULL) {
  return PyErr_NoMemory();
}
if (new != obj) {
  PyObject_Free(obj);
}
obj = new;
```

But now I get the malloc error `pointer being freed was not allocated`

How am I meant to make sure my program doesn't leak memory when using PyObject_Malloc and PyObject_Realloc?

Comment: Have you ensured that the reference count of `obj` is 1? If there are other pointers to it in existance then reallocing it isn't going to be safe.

Comment: @DavidW checking `Py_REFCNT(obj)` before every reallocation shows it's always 1

Comment: That's fine then. There's definitely cases where this this is reliably true (e.g. you've just allocated an object in C and haven't yet returned it to Python)

Comment: @DavidW since I think the memory leak comes from elsewhere, I made a new question with my full code. I wonder if you can spot anything: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66764918/3310334

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this in the exact same manner as `realloc` must be used:

```
PyObject *new = PyObject_Realloc(obj, new_size);

if (new == NULL) {
    // obj is still valid - so maybe you need to free it *here*
    PyObject_Free(obj);
    return PyErr_NoMemory();
}


// if a non-null pointer *was* returned, then obj was already
// freed and new points to the new memory area. Therefore
// assign it to obj unconditionally.
obj = new;
```

Comment: "maybe you need to free it" doesn't instil confidence, what if it crashes harder after that?

Comment: "if a non-null pointer *was* returned, then obj was already freed" how do you know?

Comment: @minseong because that is the contract.

Comment: @minseong I would be 100 % sure that it needs to be freed there in a program written by me. WIth your program I'd be just 99 % sure. It is possible to write such a spaghetti program that it would crash if you call `PyObject_Free(obj)` there but work right otherwise. I can't know what you've written.

Comment: I guess the memory leak comes from elsewhere. If you have the time to spare, could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66764918/3310334