# PyLongObject memory leak

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-extensions

There is a memory leak in my `encode` method.

```c
static const size_t _bits_per_digit = sizeof(digit) * CHAR_BIT;

/**
 * Returns a Python int storing the bitstream of the Elias gamma encoded input list.
 */
static PyObject *
encode(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj)
{
    if (!PyList_Check(obj)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Input to encode must be a list");
        return NULL;
    }

    const Py_ssize_t list_length = PyList_GET_SIZE(obj);
    size_t size = _ceil_div((size_t) PyList_GET_SIZE(obj), _bits_per_digit);

    size_t current_digit = 0;
    size_t current_bit = 0;

    PyLongObject *bstream = _PyLong_New(size);
    if (bstream == NULL) {
        return NULL; // _PyLong_New sets errors
    }

    for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < list_length; i++)
    {
        PyObject *item = PyList_GET_ITEM(obj, i);
        unsigned long number = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(item);
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) { // number overflowed or was negative
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Number at list index %zd was negative or too large", i);
            return NULL;
        } else if (number == 0) { // unencodable
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Zero at list index %zd", i);
            return NULL;
        }
        size_t N = _fast_floor_log2(number);
        size_t required_size = _ceil_div(current_digit * _bits_per_digit + current_bit + N * 2 + 1 + list_length - i - 1, _bits_per_digit);
        if (size < required_size) {
            size = required_size;
            PyLongObject *new = (PyLongObject *) PyObject_Realloc(bstream, offsetof(PyLongObject, ob_digit) + size * _bits_per_digit);
            if(new == NULL) {
                PyObject_Free(bstream);
                return PyErr_NoMemory();
            }
            bstream = new;
            PyObject_InitVar((PyVarObject*)bstream, &PyLong_Type, size);
        }
        // write leading zeroes
        size_t zeroes_left = N;
        while (zeroes_left > 0) {
            if (PyErr_CheckSignals()) {
                return NULL;
            }
            if (current_bit == 0) {
                bstream->ob_digit[current_digit] = (digit) 0;
                if (zeroes_left > _bits_per_digit) {
                    zeroes_left -= _bits_per_digit;
                    ++current_digit;
                } else {
                    current_bit += zeroes_left;
                    if (current_bit == _bits_per_digit) {
                        current_bit = 0;
                        ++current_digit;
                    }
                    zeroes_left = 0;
                }
            } else {
                digit mask = ~((digit)-1 >> current_bit); // enable the current_bit most significant bits
                bstream->ob_digit[current_digit] &= mask; // set remainder of this digit to zeroes
                digit zeroes_written = _bits_per_digit - current_bit;
                if (zeroes_left > zeroes_written) {
                    zeroes_left -= zeroes_written;
                    current_bit = 0;
                    ++current_digit;
                } else {
                    current_bit += zeroes_left;
                    if (current_bit == _bits_per_digit) {
                        current_bit = 0;
                        ++current_digit;
                    }
                    zeroes_left = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        // write the binary representation of number
        size_t bits_left = N + 1;
        while (bits_left > 0) {
            if (PyErr_CheckSignals()) {
                return NULL;
            }
            unsigned long mask = 1UL << (bits_left - 1);
            if (number & mask) {
                bstream->ob_digit[current_digit] |= ~((digit) -1 >> 1) >> current_bit;
            } else {
                bstream->ob_digit[current_digit] &= ~(~((digit) -1 >> 1) >> current_bit);
            }
            ++current_bit;
            if (current_bit == _bits_per_digit) {
                current_bit = 0;
                ++current_digit;
            }
            --bits_left;
            mask >>= 1;
        }
    }

    // remove unused digits
    if ((size - current_digit) > 1) {
        size = current_digit + 1;
        PyLongObject *new = (PyLongObject *) PyObject_Realloc(bstream, offsetof(PyLongObject, ob_digit) + size * _bits_per_digit);
        if(new == NULL) {
            PyObject_Free(bstream);
            return PyErr_NoMemory();
        }
        bstream = new;
        PyObject_InitVar((PyVarObject*)bstream, &PyLong_Type, size);
    }

    // fill leftover with zeroes, overwrite malloc randomness
    digit mask = ~((digit) -1 >> current_bit);
    bstream->ob_digit[current_digit] &= mask;

    return (PyObject *) bstream;
}
```

In Python

```
tracemalloc.start()
encoded = encode(numbers)
sleep(3) # give garbage collection time to run
size, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
tracemalloc.stop()
print("size, peak", size, peak)
print(sys.getsizeof(encoded))
```

prints

```
size, peak 17053496 17053496
2131708
```

Instead of the expected

```
size, peak 2131708 ...
2131708
```

---

Using my own type instead of `PyLongObject`, which looks identical to my eyes, leads to no memory leak at all and the output

```
size, peak 2131309 2131309
2131309
```

Here's the type that had that output

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    uint8_t data[1];
} BitStream;

static PyTypeObject BitStreamType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "elias_gamma_code.BitStream",
    .tp_dealloc = 0,
    .tp_free = PyObject_Del,
    .tp_basicsize = offsetof(BitStream, data),
    .tp_itemsize = sizeof(uint8_t),
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
};
```

So there's something special about using PyLongObject in particular that causes the massive memory usage.

My guess was that it was due to PyObject_Realloc, so I asked over here: [Use PyObject_Realloc correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66762938/3310334)

But apparently

> if a non-null pointer *was* returned, then obj was already freed

And indeed using `PyObject_Free(previous_obj)` caused `pointer being freed was not allocated` malloc errors.

---

Elias gamma encoding represents a non-zero positive binary integer as N leading zeroes, N being the bit length of the number - 1 (same as floor(log2(num))), followed by the number itself.

```
+--------+---------------+
| Number |  γ encoding   |
+--------+---------------+
|      1 |             1 |
|      2 |          0 10 |
|      3 |          0 11 |
|      4 |        00 100 |
|      5 |        00 101 |
|    ... |               |
|     15 |      000 1111 |
|     16 |   0000 1 0000 |
|    ... |               |
|     31 |   0000 1 1111 |
|     32 | 00000 10 0000 |
```

All numbers in a list can be encoded as such and concatenated. The resulting bitstream can be decoded unambiguously to the original list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In error paths, given

```
PyLongObject *bstream = _PyLong_New(size);
```

you must decrease reference to it. But you didn't do that for example here:

```
if (PyErr_Occurred()) { // number overflowed or was negative
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Number at list index %zd was negative or too large", i);
    return NULL;
} else if (number == 0) { // unencodable
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Zero at list index %zd", i);
    return NULL;
}
```

The proper C idiom is to `goto` to an error handling label:

```
    PyLongObject *bstream = NULL;

    if (!(bstream = _PyLong_New(size))) {
        goto error;
    }

    if (! some other check) {
        goto error;
    }
    
    ...
    return bstream;

error:
    // xdecref requires that the pointer is initialized in all
    // code paths, either to null or pointing to a valid live PyObject 

    Py_XDECREF(bstream);
    return NULL;
}
```

---

Another thing altogether is the question whether it is allowed to realloc a longobject at all in Python... it can break in the future.

---

Finally this one looks a bit strange:

```
size * _bits_per_digit
```

`PyObject_Realloc` takes the new size as *bytes*, so why'd you multiply by *bits* per digit - instead you must multiply by **width** (sizeof) of the digit type.

Comment: It was entirely due to the `size * _bits_per_digit` you spotted! Thanks. And thanks a lot for pointing out the idiomatic style for errors, where should I put that label? (After the return at the end of the method?)

Comment: Often the way to do it is: 1) set up all the `PyObject*` to `NULL` at the start of the function. At the end of the function have `error: xdecref all pyobjects but result; return result;` Therefore the same cleanup code is shared between the success and failure path (but `result` is `NULL` on failure).